# How long will someone that uses Tretonin live for?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

How long will someone that uses the drug Tretonin live for ? 
I know that they will gain the health benifits similar to someone that is joined with a symbiote (not sure if its the same with healing) but not using a sarcophagus. Is it also the same with their lifespan ? 
For example, a Tok'ra host lives for either 200 or 400 years (I forget which), so will the person that is using Tretonin live for about the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tretonin originally is made from symbiotes themselves therefor providing all of the symbiotes regenerative powers and extended age. So i would say a jaffa that was using tretonin would most likly live closer to a Tok'Ra is age. Thought currently they are using a synthetic tretonin which may not offer quite the same healing and age as what an actual symbiote would offer. Tretonin does still destroy the users immune system as the drug itself becomes the immune system of the host, so you have a dependency on it for life.

Comment: Would someone like a Human/ Tauri live as long as that ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure humans that never had a symbiot cannot use it.

Answer (score 3):

We have a canonical example. In the series finale, *Unending*, Teal'c

> lives for fifty years on Tretonin, and doesn't look significantly older at the end.

Comment: While Teal'c does show that you can live for at least 50 years on tretonin, he never died of old age, so we don't know for sure what the life expectancy actually is. Given that tretonin is a new invention, we're unlikely to see exactly how long it lets a person live, unless that's ever covered by a future comic or book.